# Cross-platform Fortran library with modern equivalent of sfir1d function

Tags: fortran, fft, convolution

I am working with some legacy Fortran code that calls a subroutine `sfir1d`.  Googling for the subroutine name, I found that SGI used to ship some of this code in an `SCSL` library.

http://techpubs.sgi.com/library/tpl/cgi-bin/getdoc.cgi?coll=0650&db=man&fname=/usr/share/catman/p_man/cat3/SCSL/zfir1d.z

I am wondering if there is a modern, cross-platform equivalent for the `sfir1d` function.  Is this part of the `BLAS` library?

Moreover, as listed at the webpage link above, the convolution seems to be very slow as implemented by this library in the time domain, and it would make more sense to use the FFT in the frequency domain.

Is there an accelerated cross-platform library that can perform the 1D convolution in exactly the same way?  Or perhaps it would be better to simply write my own version (not too difficult to do with an accelerated FFT library).

Comment: Intel's _Integrated Performance Primitives_ (IPP) provide accelerated 1D and 2D convolutions, tuned for most x86 CPUs (as usual, Intel claims that it is tuned for their CPUs and that it _might_ work on x86 CPUs from other chip makers). It is a C/C++ library, but you could write a wrapper to call it from Fortran too. Supported OSes are Winodws, Linux and OS X. IPP is a commercial product, but so is/was the SGI's scientific library. For maximum portability, write your own code.

Comment: Thanks, Hristo.  I didn't know about IPP, and I will look into this.  Since I work with multiple platforms, it is probably best for me to code up my own solution.  I also suspect that the SGI  library used the time-domain version of convolution, which may be slow.  From experience, I've found that most DSP (Digital Signal Processing) applications use convolution in the frequency domain since it is much quicker with FFT processing.

Comment: It _might_ give somewhat better precision to the final result if convolution is done in the time domain.

Comment: Sure - thanks for suggesting this, Hristo.